# I have a technical issue compiling with mpicc

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, mpi, ubuntu-18.04

My gcc works fine when I compile '''gcc''' but I'm trying to compile a C program with '''mpicc''' and my terminal returns this error, which deletes also the script:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The compiling instructions are: `mpicc -o p35.c`.

How could I solve this?

My gcc version:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My mpicc version:

```
mpicc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think command should be `mpicc p35.c -o p35.out`

Comment: Yeah I think that was it, thank you very much. I'll post an answer soon here

Comment: _"I have technical issue compiling with mpicc"_ is a rather uninformative question title.

Comment: @PSKP The OP previously had a single question, and answered himself as suggested by the user who answered it as a comment, and hence did **nothing** wrong. If you want to get more reps, then start posting answers instead of comments.

Answer (score 0):

#### Compiling Command is Wrong

```sh
mpicc p35.c -o p35.out
```

**Now run `p35.out` file**

```sh
./p35.out
```

I think you got this.